# Don't start a github actions workflow if already running

Tags: github-actions

I have a heavy workflow that runs for some 30+ minutes. It is triggered by making a comment on a PR. Statuses are posted/updated as the workflow runs. As long as there is only one person touching the PR, this is fine. However, it's possible for two people to send the comment and thus trigger the workflow twice.

So, if I'm 25 minutes into the workflow and somebody dumps the magic comment from a stale browser tab, I want to just finish the run in progress and not repeat all the work.

How would I prevent starting the workflow a second time, when it already runs for a given combination of PR+hash?

I know about `concurrency`, but that cancels the *previous* run. I need the opposite...

(Detecting the posted statuses seems simple, but it isn't a reliable way of deciding if anything really runs, only if a status has been ever posted.)

Comment: Did you try `skip-duplicate-actions` ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood. Do you want to wait with the second run until the first is finished or do not trigger the second at all?

Comment: KrzysztofMadej I don't want to start the second run at all.

Comment: `skip-duplicate-actions` seems to do exactly what I want, but it uses the triggering hash to determine the changes. That won't work in my case since I trigger by comment :-(